# hash link and force to reload/refresh page in emberjs && rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, hash, ember.js, href

etc, 
current page and link: '/lessons/4' which is a normal page without emberjs
and I want to redirect to

'/#/sections/2'

```html
<a href="/#/sections/2">next_page</a>
```

Because the link is with hash, it will not reload in the next_page.

So how can I force it to reload?

My current solution is

```html
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.location.reload(); window.location.href = '/#/sections/2'">Start</a>
```

Do you have any better solutions?

Comment: your question seems truncated

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to set an event handler on [hash change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756146/emberjs-router-state-does-not-change-when-the-url-hash-is-changed) that might help you. I am not familiar with emberjs.

Also, rails support [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), it is good practice to code following this principle.